# Error - unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python

I am creating a code in a file called python1.py that take two input values and calculates the percentage

```
var1,var2 = input("Give 2 integers: student mark and then what the test was out of").split() # the requested marks are split by a white space
var1,var2 = [int(x) for x in [var1, var2]] # this converts the input values to integers
percentage = round(var1/var2*100) # calculation of the percentage truncating the fractional part
print("%d out of %d is %d%%" %(var1, var2, percentage))
```

when it is run on an automatic marker it produces the following error:
Give 2 integers: student mark and then what the test was out of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "question1.py", line 1, in 
    var1,var2 = input("Give 2 integers: student mark and then what the test was out of").split() # the requested marks are split by a white space
  File "", line 1
    21 35
        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

what can I do to solve the error

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw_input` instead of input

```
var1, var2 = raw_input("Give 2 integers: student mark and then what the test was out of ").split() # the requested marks are split by a white space
```

Percentage calcualation in your code is incorrect. Here's a working code:

```
var1, var2 = raw_input("Give 2 integers: student mark and then what the test was out of ").split() # the requested marks are split by a white space
print var1, var2
var1,var2 = [int(x) for x in [var1, var2]] # this converts the input values to integers
percentage = float(var1)/float(var2)*100 # calculation of the percentage truncating the fractional part
print("%d out of %d is %d%%" %(var1, var2, percentage))
```

---

```
Give 2 integers: student mark and then what the test was out of 10 20
10 20
10 out of 20 is 50%
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using http://pythonfiddle.com/ or other similar web site?
If so, try input

```
"21 35"
```

And if `var1 < var2`, `var1 / var2` would be `0`:

```
percentage = round(var1 * 1.0 / var2 * 100)
print("%d out of %d is %d%%" %(var1, var2, percentage))
```